# How to use boost preprocessors to run a sequence of functions?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-preprocessor

For example I have a sequence of functions f1, f2 and so on with the same two argument type. I want to using macro

```
RUN((f1)(f2)(f3), a, b)
```

to run the sequence of functions with the results

```
f1(a, b), f2(a, b), f3(a, b)
```

I think boost preprocessors can help. I tried

```
#define RUN_DETAIL(pR, pData, pF) pF(a, b);
#define RUN(pFs, a, b) BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(RUN_DETAIL, BOOST_PP_EMPTY, pFs)
```

But failed. How to do it?

Found an answer as below

```
#define RUN_DETAIL(pR, pData, pF) pF pData;
#define RUN(pFs, ...) BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(RUN_DETAIL, (__VA_ARGS__), pFs)
```

This technique works also for calling a sequence of macros.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? This seems to be possible with templates.

Comment: "But failed" - *how* did it fail?

Comment: Regarding your edit: uh-uh. No. That's a totally different question so if you want to ask that please post it separately! You already have an outstanding answer to your original question below. I've rolled back your edit.

Comment: Functions are not macros are not functions.

Comment: @edit: don't do this, just type it out, it's write-once code. = default exists for a reason.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Are they really different questions? They have the same answer. Use "macro" to replace "function" to show more clearly the uses of the answer and also avoid side answers which is not a real answer because it doesn't use boost preprocessors.

Comment: @user1899020 They are different questions. Quite different, in fact. I can see how you might not realize that immediately, but please trust us on this one. Changing the question *after* sehe put so much effort into an answer is bad, as it can make his answer look like it doesn't apply to what you asked. But I think you've otherwise gotten your answer?

Comment: @user1899020: "What colour is the grass?" "What colour blood does a Vulcan have?" Are these really different questions? They have the same answer.

Comment: (inb4 pedantic people: the grass in _my_ garden.)

Comment: @user1899020 I think my answer pretty definitively ***proves*** that they most certainly do not have the same answer. This is because macros are simply not C++ language constructs. (They're preprocessor constructs that can be used "against" (okay, that's charged) your C++)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to be using macros here. See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2d068439440aa54c)**:

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/algorithm.hpp>
#include <boost/phoenix.hpp>

template <typename... F>
struct sequence_application
{
    explicit sequence_application(F... fs) : fs(fs...) { }

    template <typename... Args>
        void operator()(Args const&... args) const {
            namespace phx = boost::phoenix;
            using namespace phx::arg_names;

            boost::fusion::for_each(fs, phx::bind(arg1, phx::cref(args)...));
        }
    private:
        std::tuple<F...> fs;
};

template <typename... F>
sequence_application<F...> apply_all(F&&... fs) {
    return sequence_application<F...>(std::forward<F>(fs)...);
}
```

Let's demonstrate this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void foo(const char* v) { std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << ": " << v << "\n"; }
void bar(std::string v) { std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << ": " << v << "\n"; }

struct poly_functor {
    template <typename... T>
        void operator()(T&...) const { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; }
};
```

You can of course do the direct invocation as in the question:

```
poly_functor pf;
apply_all(&foo, &bar, pf)("fixed invocation is boring");
```

But, that's rather boring indeed. How about, we keep the compound functor around, and pass **it** to another algorithm?

```
auto combined = apply_all(&foo, &bar, pf);

boost::for_each(
        std::vector<const char*> {"hello", "world", "from", "various"},
        combined);
```

Now, try that with your macro approach. Macros are **not** first class language citizens in C++.

Finally, let's showcase that it works with variadics argument lists:

```
struct /*anonymous*/ { int x, y; } point;

// the variadic case
apply_all(pf)("bye", 3.14, point);
```

The full demo prints:

```
foo: fixed invocation is boring
bar: fixed invocation is boring
void poly_functor::operator()(T &...) const [T = <char const[27]>]
foo: hello
bar: hello
void poly_functor::operator()(T &...) const [T = <const char *const>]
foo: world
bar: world
void poly_functor::operator()(T &...) const [T = <const char *const>]
foo: from
bar: from
void poly_functor::operator()(T &...) const [T = <const char *const>]
foo: various
bar: various
void poly_functor::operator()(T &...) const [T = <const char *const>]
void poly_functor::operator()(T &...) const [T = <char const[4], const double, const <anonymous struct at test.cpp:54:5>>]
```

Comment: Pulling in `phoenix` and `fusion` when the preprocessor suffices does seem like a bit of overkill to me.

Comment: @MartinBa I tend to think of macros as a last resort. In this case, can you show the working macro solution? I'll probably upvote

Comment: The function is in fact a macro too.

Comment: @user1899020 oh great :( That makes the question pretty misleading.

Comment: @MartinBa just updated the answer with a demonstration of actually passing parameter lists and showing some ways in which this is superior to what macros can achieve.

Comment: @user1899020: You didn't "edit" it; you replaced it with an entirely different one. I rolled that back.